# ON UPDATE MySQL with doctrine DBAL

Tags: php, mysql, doctrine-orm, doctrine, onupdate

I use doctrine DBAL 2.5.2 with MySql 5.5

I have created a field with `timestamp` type and an `ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` extra.

When I change the content from phpMyAdmin the field is updated and change to the current timestamp, but when I update the content from Doctrine/dbal nothing happen. I mean everything works except the `on update`.

I call the update with `$app['db']->update('mytable', $data, array('my_id' => $id);`

How I can run the `on update` trigger from the doctrine/dbal code ?

edit :

I add this code to check if I try to change the date.

```
if (isset($data['updated'])) unset($data['updated']);
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Make sure you don't send the `date` field with your `$data` at all as an empty string will result in zeroes.
2. Make sure you're actually changing data, otherwise, the timestamp column won't get updated too.

I have set up a test project, it works fine:

```
$connectionParams = ...;
$conn = \Doctrine\DBAL\DriverManager::getConnection($connectionParams, $config);
$conn->update('user', array('name' => 'X3'), array('name' => 'X2'));
```

Table:

```
CREATE TABLE `user` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `name` text NOT NULL,
  `date` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Some test data:

```
INSERT INTO `user` (`id`, `name`, `date`) VALUES
(1, 'A', '0000-00-00 00:00:00'),
(2, 'B', '0000-00-00 00:00:00'),
(3, 'C', '0000-00-00 00:00:00'),
(4, 'F', '0000-00-00 00:00:00'),
(10, 'X2', '2015-11-10 14:47:08');
```

Can you retest and make sure you have all the parameters correct on the date field?

Comment: You right, I get all the data from the database to populate my form and I send back all the data. So my date is send too and the ON UPDATE is not executed